# Record Audio For Ten Hours in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, avfoundation

I'm having trouble with my application where I'm looking to record audio for roughly ten hours at a time. I'm not looking to save a ten hour clip, but rather listen out for short loud noises over that ten hour period and save only them.

Currently I have made a prototype using the AVFoundation framework which records audio in the background, plays it back and monitors the noise levels to check how loud the current audio is. I had an idea of how to get around my problem where I could monitor the noise levels and only save the recording if it exceeds these noise levels. Therefore only recording short second clips and saving on space.

However in order to check the noise levels the audio recorder must be recording all the time and so will currently record that full audio clip.

Could anyone offer me some guidance on the matter please?

Comment: AVAudioRecorder is meant to be used to record to file directly. Try having a look at AVCaptureSession [ https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVCaptureSession ] and at AVCaptureAudioDataOutput [ https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureAudioDataOutput_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVCaptureAudioDataOutput ]

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Do you know if I could use AVCaptureSession to record audio whilst the device is locked over a ten hour period? Then save the points of audio that were above a predetermined noise threshold.

Comment: I haven't tried using it but all seems to indicate it should be possible. You can monitor the output signal with AVCaptureAudioDataOutput and put it in a circular buffer or in two separate buffers of a second or two. Once you detect a volume above what you want to record you can start writing to file and stop recording once your monitored volume is below your stop recording threshold for a few seconds. You could even decide to write to different files with names based on date and time of starting recording.

Comment: Currently I am using two AVAudioRecorders, one to listen out for noises (audioListener) and one to actually record those noises (audioRecorder). The audioListener is always recording and getting the meter levels of the noises as it needs to be recording in order to get those levels. If those noises go above a threshold then the audioRecorder starts recording until the noises are below that threshold. I still need to do a few more tests but this method does seem to work.

I will also look at your suggestion, especially if it is the recommended way of doing things.

Thank you for the help.